# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame._freetype'

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to update PyTagCloud to Python 3, and current versions of libraries, such as PyGame.

I've got some tests passing, I can import pygame, but I get errors on "import pygame.font":

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame.font'
```

[This page](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/freetype.html) says that pygame.freetype is a replacement for pygame.font, but I get:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame._freetype'
```

when I try to import pygame.freetype, or pygame.ftcont.

I have [freetype-py](https://pypi.org/project/freetype-py/) installed and working in the same venv, and can run the wordle.py freetype sample, so freetype is working.

MacOS 10.12.6, Python 3.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it on python 3.8.x A lot of libraries do not have proper wheels yet.

Comment: I tried on 3.8, and noticed as I did it, that there was a newer dev release of pygame (pygame-2.0.0.dev20). This worked on 3.8, and also on 3.9!
Thanks for getting me to take another look at this.

Comment: Can you tick it as answered, please? I will get additional points, if you do so :) Thanks!